# Symfony-2 gives more than one validation error message

Tags: validation, symfony

My validation.yml is given:

```
    task:
        - Email: 
               message: The email "{{ value }}" is not a valid email.
        - MinLength: { limit: 50, message: You must be 50 or under to enter. }
```

My issue is that if I give "wrong-email" in the task-field it gives two error messages:

```
The email "wrong-email" is not a valid email.
You must be 50 or under to enter.
```

Actually, I want to show only one error-message at a time.
That means it should check for the validation "MinLength" only if it is a valid email.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Validation sequencing can be done using group sequences. I fixed group sequences for the YAML driver only today, so you might need to wait for the next release of the 2.0 or master branch.

```
MyEntity:
    group_sequence: [MyEntity, Extra]
    properties:
        task:
            - Email: { message: ... }
            - MinLength { limit: 50, message: ..., groups: Extra }
```

Now the constraints in group "Extra" will only be validated if all constraints in group "MyEntity" (i.e. the default group) succeed.

Comment: Your description makes it sound like a failed validation on another field (which falls into the default MyEntity group) would stop the 'MinLength' validation from happening even if 'Email' passed. Is that the case? I would want a solution where each field gets validated until it fails, regardless of the other fields.

Comment: Looking for a similar solution too @Craig . Something like the `breakChainOnFailure` option those days in ZF1: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.elements.html - Do we have this in SF2 @webmozart ?