# Prevent multiple validation errors in Symfony

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, symfony-2.1

```
$this->createFormBuilder(null, array(
    'validation_constraint' => new Collection(array(
        'randominput' => array(
            new NotBlank(),
            new Email(),
            new MyCustomConstraint()
        )
))
->add('randominput', 'text');
```

Submit result (with required attribute removed from html, with firebug):

[image]

The message from Email() constraint does not apper because inside that constraint exists a piece of code, witch I think is a clone/hardcode for NotBlank() constraint

```
if (null === $value || '' === $value) {
    return;
}
```

I think the Email() constraint should be a child of NotBlank()...

I want MyCustomConstraint() to not be executed if NotBlank() founds a violation. So it will be good if will be some option, for example "breakNextConstraintExecutionOnFirstViolation" => true. So if I set 10 constraints for one field, and 3rd constraint sets a violation, then next 7 constraints will not be executed.

If that kind of logic/option does not exists in symfony2, it will be good if I can access the 'validation' service from MyCustomConstraint class and reuse existing constraints but not write hardcode for each new constraint:

```
class MyCustomConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        // use the validator to validate the value, not hardcode
        if (count( $this->get('validator')->validateValue(
            $value,
            new NotBlank()
        )) > 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        $this->context->addViolation('MyCustomConstraint Message...');
    }
}
```

So my question is: What should I do to prevent multiple violation messages for one filed and do not use in every new constraint hardcode?

P.S. In my previous projects (not on symfony), I made forms showing only one error message. So user completes fields one by one and see only one error but not submitting the form and that fills every fields with red errors (and scares some users). But now at least I want to resolve this issue.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627337/symfony-2-gives-more-than-one-validation-error-message Should help to solve your problem

Comment: Got it (for yml). But I can't find any example how to use `group_sequence` in dynamic forms (my case)

Comment: @Artern L: That solution appears to make fields interfere with each other. If any field in the default group fails validation, none of the  constraints in the 'Extra' group get checked.

Comment: I found how to set Validation Groups for constraints: `new NotBlank(array('groups' => array('create', 'update'))`. But I can't find how to set the `group_sequence` parameter for my form (without yml)

Comment: I found a ["solution"](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5665#issuecomment-12881520) but don't know if it's right, nobody replies