# Symfony2 form validation - how display only first error message per field

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have a field with sets of validation rules:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="options", type="integer")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Min(limit = "1381", message = "Please provide number higher than 1381")
 * @Assert\Regex(pattern = "/^\d{4}$/" , message = "Four digits are expected")
 */
private $options;
```

and it seems sometimes Symfony is checking every assertion(what is good) and render every error in view(what is not expected). After submitting a form with option=5 I got folowed error messages in view.

```
Options
- Please provide number higher than 1381
- Four digits are expected
```

but when I send option = null then only one error message is displayed.

```
Options
- This value should not be blank.
```

Is there a 'switch' which causes that only one error message is rendered in template? I would like to have only one error message per field in my forms.

====== edit ======
[Solution I like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627337/symfony-2-gives-more-than-one-validation-error-message) by Bernhard Schussek
Patt thanks for pointing me there

Comment: A great way to do it would be to use [validation sequencing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627337/symfony-2-gives-more-than-one-validation-error-message) as recommended by symfony form guru @Bernhard :)

Comment: This is the trick I needed -  please type it as answer to let me up vote it. Thanks

Comment: Glad this helped, don't worry about the vite. This is @Bernhard answer. Maybe you could upvote his answer and edit your question so that people can have a link to Bernard answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to modify the template/block for a form error block [application wide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#twig) (so that every one of your forms in a template will get the desired behaviour). Or override the form layout on a [per template basis](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-1-inside-the-same-template-as-the-form).

If you go and look at the [default form layout](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig) that ships with the Symfony standard edition you can see on [line 273](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L273) the `form_errors` twig `block` is defined.

You could override this block in a given template (as per the documentation), to only echo one element from the `errors` array:

```twig
{# SomeTemplate:Default:index.html.twig #}
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block form_errors %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
    {{ errors[0].message }}
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_errors %}

{% block content %}
    {# ... render the form #}

    {{ form_rest(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: errors|length will be always 1 if error available or 0 if not.
So even you have 2 errors (2 fields with errors) - you will get for field {{ id }} always count == 1.

My proposition is to use JS and hide more than 1 errors